# Json Decode for PHP Array does not return any result

Tags: php, json, gnip

After several research on Gnip, I integrated it into my app and I managed to add new rules and get stream results from Gnip as well but now I have a problem in converting it to PHP array and display it

I used CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE, to not to print the curl result and I store it to a variable and decode it using the json_decode function and I print it but still get an empty page.

If someone can help me on this it will be a big time saving for me

Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
 $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $stream_url,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "gzip",
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => $user.":".$pass,
        CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION => "print_out_data",
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME=> 60,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,

 //CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true // uncomment for curl verbosity

    ));


    $content = curl_exec($ch);

    $arr = json_decode($content, true);
    $foo = $arr['id']; 
    $bar = $arr['objectType']; 

   print_r($foo);
    print_r($bar);
```

The result I get when printing

```
{"id":"tag:search.twitter.com,2005:304468052219662336","objectType":"activity","actor":{"objectType":"person","id":"id:twitter.com:348088144","link":"http://www.twitter.com/Devin_Giordan0","displayName":"ᎠƎϑᎥИ ᗩИ✞ℍ⚙ИУ","postedTime":"2011-08-03T21:21:01.000Z","image":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3271229767/481419170edf2c639441ce43cd540f0e_normal.jpeg","summary":"I will see a Million Before I diee\nInstagram-Youngnrecklessss\nFollow me and ill follow back \nFuck what people think, stay real. ","links":[{"href":null,"rel":"me"}],"friendsCount":476,"followersCount":265,"listedCount":0,"statusesCount":2773,"twitterTimeZone":null,"verified":false,"utcOffset":null,"preferredUsername":"Devin_Giordan0","languages":["en"],"location":{"objectType":"place","displayName":"Brooklyn, Ny"}},"verb":"share","postedTime":"2013-02-21T05:50:15.000Z","generator":{"displayName":"Echofon","link":"http://www.echofon.com/"},"provider":{"objectType":"service","displayName":"Twitter","link":"http://www.twitter.com"},"link":"http://twitter.com/Devin_Giordan0/statuses/304468052219662336","body":"RT @julianneromero1: All I wanna do is make youuu happy ","object":{"id":"tag:search.twitter.com,2005:304448192165076993","objectType":"activity","actor":{"objectType":"person","id":"id:twitter.com:383846395","link":"http://www.twitter.com/julianneromero1","displayName":"julieeeeee","postedTime":"2011-10-02T16:35:38.000Z","image":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3259175129/bdd9337b0e266c851a471f7034ca319a_normal.jpeg","summary":"Old enough to know better, young enough to not give a fuck. ✊","links":[{"href":null,"rel":"me"}],"friendsCount":409,"followersCount":483,"listedCount":0,"statusesCount":18986,"twitterTimeZone":"Quito","verified":false,"utcOffset":"-18000","preferredUsername":"julianneromero1","languages":["en"]},"verb":"post","postedTime":"2013-02-21T04:31:20.000Z","generator":{"displayName":"Twitter for iPhone","link":"http://twitter.com/download/iphone"},"provider":{"objectType":"service","displayName":"Twitter","link":"http://www.twitter.com"},"link":"http://twitter.com/julianneromero1/statuses/304448192165076993","body":"All I wanna do is make youuu happy ","object":{"objectType":"note","id":"object:search.twitter.com,2005:304448192165076993","summary":"All I wanna do is make youuu happy ","link":"http://twitter.com/julianneromero1/statuses/304448192165076993","postedTime":"2013-02-21T04:31:20.000Z"},"twitter_entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]}},"twitter_entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"julianneromero1","name":"julieeeeee","id":383846395,"id_str":"383846395","indices":[3,19]}]},"retweetCount":5,"gnip":{"matching_rules":[{"value":"Happy","tag":null}],"klout_score":42,"language":{"value":"en"}}} {"id":"tag:search.twitter.com,2005:304468052492300288","objectType":"activity","actor":{"objectType":"person","id":"id:twitter.com:1192574623","link":"http://www.twitter.com/Krystlegtsi","displayName":"Tracee Pavlik","postedTime":"2013-02-18T09:14:11.000Z","image":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/3271765828/92aae4995378723671641594159a6ad7_normal.jpeg","summary":null,"links":[{"href":"http://tinyurl.com/b23r4ee","rel":"me"}],"friendsCount":20,"followersCount":0,"listedCount":0,"statusesCount":4,"twitterTimeZone":null,"verified":false,"utcOffset":null,"preferredUsername":"Krystlegtsi","languages":["en"]},"verb":"post","postedTime":"2013-02-21T05:50:15.000Z","generator":{"displayName":"web","link":"http://twitter.com"},"provider":{"objectType":"service","displayName":"Twitter","link":"http://www.twitter.com"},"link":"http://twitter.com/Krystlegtsi/statuses/304468052492300288","body":"It was an Amazing event tonight ...and makes me happy to see the president is educated speaks English Mashallah.","object":{"objectType":"note","id":"object:search.twitter.com,2005:304468052492300288","summary":"It was an Amazing event tonight ...and makes me happy to see the president is educated speaks English Mashallah.","link":"http://twitter.com/Krystlegtsi/statuses/304468052492300288","postedTime":"2013-02-21T05:50:15.000Z"},"twitter_entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[]},"retweetCount":0,"gnip":{"matching_rules":[{"value":"Happy","tag":null}],"language":{"value":"en"}}}
```

Comment: Can you share what comes inside $content variable?

Comment: what you see if you print $content before "json_decode"? is there any kind of response?

Comment: Ohh I won't get any result when printing $content but with out  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE it print me json result and I'll paste the result in my question tab now

Answer (score 0):

1. check the content in `$content`
2. If content is there then check (`print_r($arr)`), check the structure and print according to it.

Comment: Hello thanks for the response, but the problem is $content is empty and won't print anything.

Comment: @doubleD :  Check your curl

Comment: when I remove "CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE" then it prints the result and I have paste the result in my question

Comment: Ok, now you will get the output, try :  `echo $foo; echo $bar;`

Comment: still I get only the json list printed on my page but not the echo $foo; echo $bar;

Comment: Can you paste that out put here

Comment: the out put result has paste on my question tab

Comment: Check in your phpinfo whether json is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have non-UTF characters in **displayName** in the rsult string

You should use only UTF-characters for JSON encode/decode functions.